# Programmatically get method of XML button onClick attribute in Android

Tags: android, reflection

In Android, specifying a method in a button's XML `onClick` property causes that method to get called on button click. Given the button view, is there a way to find out what method is going to get called programmatically? I've looked at the available public methods for Views, but I can't find anything in regards to getting view properties that might help. I know that Android creates an onClick listener in the `android.view.View$1` class for buttons defined in this way, and I was hoping there might be a way to use reflection to find the method I'm after.

Edit: I'm not building an app, but rather a library that watches button clicks. As such, I'd like to figure out what method is going to be called. I've already figured out how to handle buttons with traditional onClick listeners in the code, so the XML button onClick is the last case I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

While it is *possible*, you really shouldn't do it.

It'll make your app dependent on the internal (private!) implementation of the framework, which is a terrible idea. Your app may stop working in a future Android version. Or even just on some devices, if a device manufacturer changes something internally (which they're allowed to do). Something as simple as a changed variable name may trip up your reflection code.

There should be a better way to achieve your goal here.

EDIT: with the added information, and some extra thinking, I realized that you may be able to do this without reflection. You should be able to parse the XML layout with the help of [`Resources.getLayout(int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getLayout%28int%29), finding the appropriate button id:s and reading the `android:onClick` value from each.

Comment: You mention it being possible-- how? I'm already using some of the private Android API in my code. Also, I've updated the question with what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, judging by your question I assume that you know both the XML and programmatic methods for assigning onClickListerners...

but I dont understand why you would want to programmatically change the onClick attribute.

If you want to dynamically change the method that is called when the button is pressed, then you can do that a variety of ways, the easiest of which is simply using a state, then checking that state in the onClick method and acting accordingly...

There is probably a better way of achieving this, but is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: I don't want to change the attribute, just get the method name. I'm working on a library and I'd like to watch when the button has been clicked.